# Modal fade doesn´t dissapear

Tags: javascript, html, css

i´m having a problem with this modal, when i click cancel i want the modal to close it happens, but the fade background doesn't and as far as i know i´m not doing anything wrong but it doesn´t work. :/ Can you please help me?
Thank you so much :D

```
<div id="id01">

<div class="modal fade" id="login" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2 class="modal-title" id="login">Iniciar Sesión<button type="button" class="close navbar-btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button></h2>


      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">




 <span></span> <label for="psw"><b>Correo Electrónico</b></label>
     <span><img src="images/mail.png"></span> <input type="password"  name="psw" required  style="border-radius: 5px; border-color: 1px solid #d8d8d6;">

  <label for="psw"><b>Contraseña</b></label>
      <span><img src="images/key.png"></span><input type="password"  name="psw" required style="border-radius: 5px; border-color: 1px solid #d8d8d6;">

<hr>

<p>¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</p>

   <button type="button" class="btn"  style="color: #000000; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" >Cancelar</button>


   <button type="button" class="btn"  style="background-color: #92CD00; color: #ffffff; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">Iniciar Sesión</button>


        </div>
      </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: why don't you use `data-dismiss` ?

Comment: Solved with data-dismiss Thank you so much :)